# Pressing power button during photo viewing with share menu on results in black screen afterward

Tags: java, android

Android system's default photo viewing app is used as the default viewer. It functions normally.

The code for photo viewing button is as follows:

```
//view source image
    public void viewSourceClicked(View view){
        Uri uri = getImageUri(this, MethodCommons.convertByteArrayToBitmap(itemToBeEdited.getOriginalImage()));
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Except, when viewer's share button is pressed showing the share menu, if the user presses power button (closes the screen), then clicking this button after resuming the activity results only in a black screen.

Restarting the app containing the photo-viewing button does not resolve the issue.

This black screen can only be resolved by opening the default photo viewing app and click the share button once. So I figure that it relates to photo viewer's share activity being left open somehow.

How to prevent such black screen from occurring? any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I figured out that this resulted from using `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage`.

Using `FileProvider` in place of `insertImage` solved the problem.